# Out of position error bar on stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

The error bars are out of position right now.

I tried to position them using ggplot:

```
ggplot(d.Mean, aes(x=Treatment, y=Flux.m, fill=Plant)) +
  geom_bar(size=4, stat="identity", position="stack") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Flux.m - Flux.se, ymax=Flux.m + Flux.se), 
                width=.2, stat="identity") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  labs(x="Treatment", y="N uptake %") +
  mytheme +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=15)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_grey()
```

my data

```
    Treatment Plant Flux.m Flux.se
    NC  Weed    1.1907929   0.162910442
    NC  Wheat   0.2198656   0.009046636
    NF  Weed    0.5080035   0.116434029
    NF  Wheat   0.6842919   0.073096108
    TC  Weed    0.1323349   0.024147990
    TC  Wheat   0.2239926   0.075459460
    TF  Weed    0.1435406   0.019167675
    TF  Wheat   0.5904143   0.066450625
```

Right now it's out of position. I want to put it on top of the bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_errorbar` does not know about the stacking in your `geom_bar` layer, so you need to add a helper column to tell it where to start from with stacked y's:

```
d.Mean %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  arrange(Treatment, desc(Plant)) %>%
  mutate(Flux.m_cuml = cumsum(Flux.m)) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=Treatment,y=Flux.m,fill=Plant))+
  geom_bar(size=4,stat="identity",position="stack")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Flux.m_cuml - Flux.se, ymax=Flux.m_cuml + Flux.se), 
                width=.2, stat="identity")+
  guides(fill=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_grey() +
  labs(x="Treatment",y="N uptake %")+ 
  #mytheme+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=15))
```

[image]